# DataJointError: Found a part table without its master table

Tags: datajoint

I am using datajoint python `'0.12.8'`.
When trying to delete from an upstream table, I get the following error message:
`DataJointError: Found a part table "someschema"."table_part-table" without its master table.` I can preview `table` as well as its part table without issues.

The delete goes through when calling it directly on the `table`. However, even when the entries are gone from that table, calling `.delete()` on any upstream table still results in the error above.

I am initialising `someschema` in that session via:

```
someschema = dj.schema('the_correct_database')
someschema.spawn_missing_classes()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updating to `datajoint-0.13.1` fixed this issue for me.